# Number of Products next to the Filter by brands - Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, foreach, cakephp-3.0

Friends, I created a menu of brands to filter products.
I am trying to put next to the brand, the number of products contained.

I'm generating the branding menu this way:

BrandsCell.php

```
.
$this->loadModel('Brands');

$query = $this->Brands->find('all');
$this->set('brands', $query);
```

display.ctp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <div class="card mb-3">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h6 class="card-title text-muted">Brands</h6>
            <hr>
            <?php foreach ($brands as $brand): ?>
            

            <div class="mt-1"><?php echo $this->Html->link($brande->name, array('controller' => 'Brands', 'action' => 'search_brands', $brand->id), array('escape' => false));?>
                <b class="badge badge-pill badge-light float-right">***//Product Counter***</b>  
            </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I enter the brand id through the marca_id, it works well.

```
        $data = $this->Products->find();
        $data->select(['Products.id', $data->func()->count('Brands.id')])
        ->matching('Brands')
        ->group(['Products.id'])
        ->where(['Products.brand_id' => 5]);

        $total = $data->count();
        var_dump($total);
```

But I have difficulties for that in the foreach to be displayed next to each brand. I did it but without success!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <div class="card mb-3">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h6 class="card-title text-muted">Brands</h6>
            <hr>
            <?php foreach ($brands as $brand): ?>
                <?php foreach ($data as $total): ?>

            
            <div class="mt-1"><?php echo $this->Html->link($brand->name, array('controller' => 'Brands', 'action' => 'search_brands', $brand->id), array('escape' => false));?>
                <b class="badge badge-pill badge-light float-right"><?php echo $total->count();?></b>  
            </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Erro: Notice (8): Undefined offset: 1 [CORE/src/Database/FieldTypeConverter.php, line 134]

My final display.ctp looked like this:

```
public function display()
    {
        $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('loja');
        $this->loadModel('Brands');
        $this->loadModel('Products');

        $data = $this->Products->find();
        $data->select(['Products.id', $data->func()->count('Brands.id')])
        ->matching('Brands')
        ->group(['Products.id'])
        ->where(['Products.brand_id' => 5]);
        
        $query = $this->Brands->find('all');
        $this->set('brands', $query);
        $this->set('data', $data);
    }
```

I appreciate if anyone can help me!

Comment: try to implement and use https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/behaviors/counter-cache.html

Comment: Why are you filtering to Brand ID 5 in `->where(['Products.brand_id' => 5]);`  ? Is that what you want, just Brand ID 5? The description & code suggest you just want a count of products for each brand - trying to understand this line.

Comment: this was a test to receive the count of the brand's products with an id of 5. It works when I enter the id. but I need this to happen next to the loop that generates the brand names. That is my difficulty.

Comment: Thank you. I read the documentation. I've already configured it, but I'm not sure how to handle it in the cell I'm using. @ahoffner